# Using Firely how can I parse the data from the participant section of a HL7.Fhir.Model.Appointment JSON response?

Tags: c#, json, hl7-fhir

Using Hl7.Fhir.R4 (2.0.1)

When I receive an API response for an appointment there is a section of participants, using the Firely package, how can I extract specific participant data?

For example, for an appointment I have this section in the JSON for the appointment Participants.

```
"participant": [
{
    "actor": {
        "reference": "https://url/fhir/v2/Practitioner/111",
        "display": "https://url/fhir/v2/Practitioner/111"
    }
},
{
    "actor": {
        "reference": "https://url/fhir/v2/Location/222",
        "display": "https://url/fhir/v2/Location/222"
    }
},
{
    "actor": {
        "reference": "https://url/fhir/v2/Patient/333",
        "display": "https://url/fhir/v2/Patient/333"
    }
}
]
```

If there is a practitioner actor I want to create a new string set to the ID of the practitioner; (111) in the example above. What is the proper way to extract that information from the reference URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ITypedElement and FhirPath to get to the data you need.
Add these using statements:

```cs
using Hl7.Fhir.Model;
using Hl7.Fhir.ElementModel;
using Hl7.FhirPath;
```

And then you can get a list with the ids of the Practitioners with this code:

```cs
List<string> practitionerList = new List<string>();

var typedApp = [yourAppointmentResource].ToTypedElement();

foreach (var p in typedApp.Select("participant.actor"))
{
    var r = new ResourceIdentity(p.ParseResourceReference().Reference);
    if (r.ResourceType.Equals("Practitioner"))
        practitionerList.Add(r.Id);
}
```